# ajax appended list-group-item's do not trigger click events

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have an accordion that is populated via Django Template tags. In side each accordion item i have a list-group. The list-group' items are populated on DomReady via ajax. This works great. However, I need the list-group-items to be able to trigger another ajax call so I can query the database and render the list-group-item's related objects in another div. If i hard code an item it works fine, but the ajax created ones do not trigger an event. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you very much.

Ajax/Html:

```
<div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
    {%for fabCatagory in fab_categories%}
      <div class="panel panel-primary">
        <div class="panel-heading"> 
         <h4 class="panel-title">
            <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#  {{fabCatagory.categoryId}}" id="{{fabCatagory.categoryId}}btn"> 
                {{fabCatagory}}
            </a>
          </h4>
<script type="text/javascript">

         $(document).ready(function(){


                  $.ajax({
                          dataType: 'json',
                          type: 'GET',
                          url: '/companion/topic/{{fabCatagory}}/',

                          success: function(result){
                                      for(var i=0; i < result.topics.length; i++){
                                         $("#{{fabCatagory.categoryId}}topics").append(

                                              "<a id='"+result.topics[i].topicId+"' class='list-group-item' ><li>"+result.topics[i].topic+"</li></a>"

                                           );//end append


                                       }//end for 

                                     },//end success

                    });//end Ajax
                    });//end </script>



</div>
      <div id="{{fabCatagory.categoryId}}" class="panel-collapse collapse">
          <div class="panel-body">

               <div id="{{fabCatagory.categoryId}}topics" class="list-group">

                           <!--Ajax Data Goes Here-->

               </div>       
           </div>
      </div>
</div>

</div>

 <script type="text/javascript">    
        var topicLinkId = $(".list-group").attr('id');
        $("#"+topicLinkId).on('click', function(){ //This doesn't work
                        console.log('success');//this will be replaced, ajax function

        }) ;         

 </script>
                       {%endfor%}

        </div>
```

Comment: on success of ajax request i think u have to bind click event on newly added items

Comment: Dave, Thank you so much for the comments. That worked thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on success of ajax request.You have to bind click event for newly added items, so that DOM gets updated... You have to add the rebinding in the success handler.

Answer (score 2):

The AJAX requests are happening after the document loads and are asynchronous. You have no guarantee when the AJAX response will happen. You're attaching events immediately, so the elements you're adding to the page with AJAX aren't there yet. You should look into delegated events instead.

Depending on your version of jQuery, you would want to do something like:

```
// jQuery 1.7+
$(document).on('click', '.list-group', function(e){
    console.log('success');
}):

// older versions
$('.list-group').live('click', function(e){
    console.log('success');
});
```

You would only need to create this event handler once, so you should remove it from your `{%for loop%}`.

Basically, you can set a click event handler on the root document object and have it only trigger if the target element matches some CSS query - in this case `.list-group` is the target. It will work for any elements added after the event handler is set and removes the need to

You can read the documentation more here: [jQuery .on()](https://api.jquery.com/on/)

---

Alternatively, you could bind events after adding the elements in your success function individually to each element.

```
success: function(result){
    for(var i = 0; i < result.topics.length; i++){
        $("#{{fabCatagory.categoryId}}topics").append(
            $("<a id='"+result.topics[i].topicId+"' class='list-group-item' ><li>"+result.topics[i].topic+"</li></a>").
            bind('click', function(e){
                console.log('success');
            });
        ).
    }
},
```

But, with this method, each link would have it's own separate event handler function defined.